# Changing object type from string or list [Python]

Tags: python, types, casting, ordereddictionary

I have a small problem.

I'm trying to make a function for creating an ordered dictionary by retriving attributes of model object by the names. Models are based on data from databases and sometimes they should be converted. If list element is a string - there is no problem, ODictionary is created, and it's working. But If I want to convert for example int to string - there is a problem.
I made it with tuples. The first element is the name of new OrderedDictionary item, second should be the right type.

For example :
    elementValue = getattr(element[1], element[0])
With ("id", int) i'm getting "AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'id'" 
So its wrong option...

It's my first time with getattr. There is no problem with basic usage (for me) when I have to retrieve object att by the name but how to cast to different type from a given str type?

Comment: What type do you want to cast your string to?

Answer (score 1):

> `elementValue = getattr(element[1], element[0])`
>
> With `("id", int)` i'm getting `"AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'id'"` So its wrong option...

The signature for `getattr()` is `object, attrname[, default]` - `object` being the object you want to get the attribute from, `attrname` the attribute name (as string), and `default` an optional default value if `object` has no attribute `attrname` (if you don't pass `default` and `object` has no attribute `attrname` you get an `AttributeError`). Obviously `getattr()` is not going to do any kind of type conversion, this is something you'll have to do by yourself.

You didn't post enough of your code to give you more than a few hints but assuming you have a list of `("attrname", typeconverter)` (where `typeconverter` is any callable taking the original attribute value and returning the converted value), what you want would look something like:

```
def to_odict(obj, attrlist):
    od = OrderedDict()
    for attrname, converter in attrlist:
        # TODO : error handling ???
        raw_val = getattr(obj, attrname)
        val = converter(raw_val)
        od["attrname"] = val
    return od
```